# How to animate svg path on reaching certain point in page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, gsap

I want to replicate the effect in : [Animating svg path](http://codepen.io/nsayenko/pen/mRBGoB) but I want the svg's furthur down the page and when the user scrolls to that section the effect will be triggered and not on click of any link. On scrolling back up it will again morph back. I think it can be done using GSAP but till now I am not able to get it to work. And also if anyone can explain what's going on with :

```
[].forEach.call(links, function (el, i, els) {
el.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var animateTo = this.getAttribute("href").substring(1);

    [].forEach.call(els, function (el) {
        if (el !== this) {
            el.classList.remove("active");
        } else {
            this.classList.add("active");
        }
    }, this);

    event.preventDefault();
    this.classList.add("active");
    getPaths(animateTo);
});
});
```

I don't understand what is the (el, i, els) passed as the function parameter. I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this. [scrollmagic](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/svg_drawing.html)